# AngularJS error with nested controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have diferents controllers in my app.

**player.php:**

```
<html ng-app="decibels-interactive" lang="en">
<body ng-controller="InteractiveController as interactCtrl">
```

player.php have its respective **player.js** with its .controller running correctly.

Now, I have the menu bar in menu.php, where I use in **player.php** document, imported with:

```
<html ng-app="decibels-interactive" lang="en">
<body ng-controller="InteractiveController as interactCtrl">

<?php include('includes/menu.php'); ?>
//here some html code
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I am trying to create a **menu.js** without success. I get the next error:

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/ng/areq?p0=menu&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined...

**menu.php**

```
<div class="navbar-fixed"  ng-controller="menu2">
  //some html code
</div>
```

**menu.js:**

```
app.controller('menu2', function($scope) {

 $scope.content = '';
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: error say that not defined _menu_ but in you sample only `InteractiveController` and `menu2`

Answer (score 1):

The name of the controller inside the HTML and the JS doesn't match.
In html `InteractiveController` and you named the contoller `menu2`.

This would fix the problem.

```
app.controller('InteractiveController', function($scope) {
    $scope.content = '';
});
```

Comment: ok, thank you. I have just tried:  
MENU.PHP-->
<div class="navbar-fixed"  ng-controller="InteractiveController as menu2"> and in MEMU.JS --> app.controller('menu2', function($scope){}); and everithing works ok now :). ////
I have another question: If I have another .php with a diferent ng-app name and a diferent ng-controller name; there is a way that I could import the MENU.php?? Thank you.

Comment: @Jordi45454, you can define menu in separate module and use it as dependency where you want

Comment: so then, where I should define the menu as a separated module? Sorry! I'm new with AngularJS hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Have u included your menu controller in html page. Its controller name is mismatched and its not included in that page